# Odd values with timepicker and SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

Tags: java, android

I have a `TimePicker` in my app that can select the amount of time for playback of a song, im having issues with getting the time remaining to display properly with the `CountDownTimer`im using, everything is pretty much going on behind the scenes in milliseconds of course and i think im doing the conversion right but all i see on the screen is just completely wrong values.

When i just make a test CountDownTimer with 3600000(1hour) as first argument, everything works fine, but when i put timepicker to 0 and minute to 1 , like i want just 1 minute of playback , it displays 12 hours and what seems like random values in the minutes and seconds slots. `tp.getCurrentHour();` returns zero when set to zero and `tp.getCurrentMinute();` returns one as expected, seems like something is happening with this part, cant figure out what yet:

playtime = (hour * (60 * 60 * 1000)) + (min * (60 * 1000));
                        startime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

Why is `tv2.setText("totaltest "+startime+playtime);` displaying a value of 6000046929803??? That is obviously wrong...

Here is the the rest of the code:

```
                TimePicker tp =(TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    long hour = tp.getCurrentHour();
                                    long min = tp.getCurrentMinute();
                                    playtime = (hour * (60 * 60 * 1000)) + (min * (60 * 1000));
                                    startime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
tv2.setText("totaltest "+startime+playtime);
            timer = new CountDownTimer(startime+playtime,1000){

                                @Override
                                public void onFinish() {
                                    tv.setText("finished");
                                }

                                //@SuppressLint("ParserError")
                                @Override
                                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                                    String display = DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(millisUntilFinished/1000);

                                    tv.setText(display);

                                }

                            }.start();
```

Comment: i just tried your code, word for word, and it seems to work fine. it looks plenty human readable to me. i don't exactly know what the issue is. what format did you want exactly? and what did you mean by skips the first iteration? i know that it seems to skip the last "tick" at times.

Comment: I have `tp.setIs24HourView(true);` in `onCreate()` so the AM/PM go away, when someone picks like 1 minute from the picker the song and `countdowntimer` should go for 1 minute and should start at 00:01:00. When i set hour to 0 and minute to one, instead the `textview` says starts at 11:40:50. Now when i just set up a mock `CountDowntimer` `timer = new CountDownTimer(3600000,1000)` for an hour it works just fine, guess im just having an issue/misunderstanding with timepicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
String display = DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(millisUntilFinished/1000);
```

That does the conversion for you.

and:

```
timer = new CountDownTimer(playtime,1000){
```

as CounterDownTimer is expecting the amount of milliseconds to run.

Comment: I had to use `formatElapsedTime(millisUntilFinished/1000)` since it expects argument in seconds, thats good as it scales automatically when there arent anymore hours, my main issue though is just rigging the timepicker to work how i want it to, since when i put timepicker to 0 hours and 1 minute the textview shows up with 36 hours.

Comment: I corrected the the mistake in the answer. I've also added what I believe will correct the time picker issue.